# Socket Javascript não conecta (Stomp + RabbitMQ)

Tags: javascript, socket, websocket, rabbitmq

Estou tentando estabelecer uma comunicação entre o RabbitMQ e o Javascript, para recuperar as informações de log que são enviadas para um tópico do RabbitMQ, porém sem sucesso.
No console é exibida a seguinte informação:

```
Opening Web Socket...
WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.224.200.196:61613/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
Whoops! Lost connection to ws://10.224.200.196:61613/
```

Essa é o meu código para conexão no Javascript:

```
   var test = {
            client: null,
            onConnect: function () {
                client.subscribe("add-on", this.onMessage, {ack: 'client'});
                console.log('connected');
            },
            onMessage: function (message) {
                console.log(message);
                message.ack();
            },
            onError: function () {
                console.log('error');
            },
            connect: function () {
                this.client = Stomp.client('ws://10.224.200.196:61613/', 'v11.stomp');
                this.client.connect('test', 'test', this.onConnect, this.onError, '/');
            }
        };
        test.connect();
```

O usuário está criado no RabbitMQ como "monitoring"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O plugin stomp foi habilitado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já criei o tópico através do RabbitMQ

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu recebo essas mensagens no log do RabbitMQ

```
=INFO REPORT==== 4-Oct-2017::08:05:07 ===
accepting STOMP connection <0.672.0> (10.224.200.188:56652 -> 10.224.200.196:61613)

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Oct-2017::08:09:07 ===
closing STOMP connection <0.672.0> (10.224.200.188:56652 -> 10.224.200.196:61613)
```

Como faço para conectar e receber as mensagens?

Já usei diversos tutoriais, os últimos foram:

https://dzone.com/articles/easy-messaging-stomp-over

https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema acontece por causa da porta de conexão que deve ser "15674".

Alterar o código:

```
this.client = Stomp.client('ws://10.224.200.196:61613/', 'v11.stomp');
```

Por:

```
this.client = Stomp.client('ws://10.224.200.196:15674/ws', 'v11.stomp');
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo do código alterado:

```
var test = {
        client: null,
        onConnect: function () {
            client.subscribe("/topic/add-on", this.onMessage, {ack: 'client'});
            console.log('connected');
        },
        onMessage: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
            message.ack();
        },
        onError: function () {
            console.log('error');
        },
        connect: function () {
            client = Stomp.client('ws://10.224.200.196:15674/ws', 'v11.stomp');
            client.connect('test', 'test', this.onConnect, this.onError, '/');
        }
    };
    test.connect();
```

Segue o link da documentação

https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html